# Getting image url from JSON response using AngularJS and wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, angularjs

I am trying to fetch an image from a json API using angularjs.
I am using a html file for fetching the image,but i think i am missing something,it doesn't work.
Here's my html:

```
<li ng-repeat="post in posts">
  <a ng-click="clickToOpen({{post.id}})">{{post.title}}</a><p> img src="{{post.attachments.url}}"></p>      
</li>
```

And my JSON:

```
"attachments": [
            {
               "id": 15534,
               "url": "http://www.grandlakebusinessjournal.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Tera-Mirand-Shores-Platt-Phanse-One2.jpg",
               "slug": "tera-mirand-shores-platt-phanse-one-3",
               "title": "Tera Mirand Shores Platt Phanse One",
               "description": "",
               "caption": "",
               "parent": 15455,
               "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
               "images": []
            }

         ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) and be careful about your img tag, it does miss a < at the beginning

```
<img ng-src="{{post.attachments.url}}" />
```

Comment: when you check it in inspect element.. do you bind the url in ng-src?

Comment: on chrome inspect element, can you see the binded URL in html correctly?

Comment: i have seen only <img ng-src>,not the url

Comment: what to do??Plz help me

Answer (score -2):

Try using the following:

```
ng-src="{{post.attachments[0].url}}"
```

instead of original `src="{{post.attachments.url}}"` ([see documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/docs/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)).